# Execute command if player has bow with certain tag

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I have these commands and I want it to only explode the arrow if the player has a bow with the "explode" tag.

Here are the commands (courtesy of AntVenom)

```
"*" Means that all blocks under it have that property

[Repeat,*Unconditional,*Always Active]
/execute at @e[type=Arrow] ~ ~ ~ run /scoreboard players set @e[c=1,r=0,type=Arrow] inGround 1 {inGround:1b}
[*Chain]
/execute at @e[type=Arrow] ~ ~ ~ run /particle lava ~ ~ ~ .5 .5 .5 .5 30 .5

/execute at @e[type=Arrow,score_inGround_min=1] ~ ~ ~ run /summon PrimedTnt ~ ~1 ~ {Fuse:0}

/kill @e[type=Arrow,score_inGround_min=1]
```

I could use https://mcstacker.net/ but i'm confused on what to put where.
Any help?
I had to bump this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `execute as @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id=“bow”,tag:{explode:1b}}}] run say hi`

To give yourself the bow do `give @s bow {explode:1b}`